# Cassandra Snapshot and Restart

Tags: bash, shell, cron, cassandra

Being a level 1 novice in Linux (Ubuntu 9), shell and cron, I've had some difficulty figuring this out. Each night, I'd like to take a snapshot of our Cassandra nodes and restart the process.

Why? Because our team is hunting down a memory leak that requires a process restart every 3 weeks or so. The root cause has been difficult to track down. In the meantime, I'd like to put these cron jobs in place to reduce service interruption.

Thanks in advance for anyone who has some of these already figured out!

Comment: I guess there have been no answers because people can't figure out what the question exactly is. How to set a cron job? this seems an issue for ServerFault anyway.

Comment: Figured I would answer your question here as well in case others find it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general procedure is:

1. Run nodetool drain (http://www.riptano.com/docs/0.6/utilities/nodetool#nodetool-drain) on the node
2. Run nodetool snapshot
3. Kill the cassandra process
4. Start the cassandra process

When running nodetool snapshot, it is very important that you have JNA set up and working. This includes:

1. Having jna.jar in Cassandra's lib directory and either:
2. Running Cassandra as root, or
3. Increasing the memory locking limit using 'ulimit -l' or something like /etc/security/limits.conf

If this is all correct, you should see a message about "mlockall" succeeding in the logs on startup.

The other thing to keep an eye on is your disk space usage; this will grow as compactions occur and the old SSTables are replaced (but their snapshots remain).